# BLE writeValueForCharacteristic fails on second use

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have successfully setup my code as a `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheral` delegate and can connect to my Bluetooth device, implementing all callbacks and methods just fine. However, I can only set a value using the `writeValueForCharacteristic` method once. If I try to issue a second command then it's just ignored - almost like it's not being sent at all. I know the device is working as I can use use a test app by the same company to control it.

I've also tried implementing the `CBWriteCharacteristicWithResponse` method, which fires as expected with no errors.

```
- (void) setLEDState {
    char testDataPacketStart[] = {0xa0};
    char testDataHeader[] = {0x05, 0x00};
    char testDataPayload[] = {0x20, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

    if (_isLEDLit == false) {
       testDataPayload[4] = 0xff;
       _isLEDLit = true;
    }
    else {
        _isLEDLit = false;
    }

    NSData *testDataHeaderObject = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:testDataHeader length:2];
    NSData *testDataPayloadObject = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:testDataPayload length:5];

    UInt16 crc1 = [[self class] computeCRC16:testDataHeaderObject startingCRC:0xffff];
    UInt16 crc2 = [[self class] computeCRC16:testDataPayloadObject startingCRC:crc1];

    char testDataAssembledPacket[10] = {};
    testDataAssembledPacket[0] = testDataPacketStart[0];
    testDataAssembledPacket[1] = testDataHeader[0];
    testDataAssembledPacket[2] = testDataHeader[1];

    int lenPacket = sizeof(testDataPayload);
    for (int byteCount = 0; byteCount < lenPacket; byteCount++) {
        testDataAssembledPacket[byteCount + 3] = testDataPayload[byteCount];
    }

    testDataAssembledPacket[8] = (UInt8)(crc2 & 0xFF);
    testDataAssembledPacket[9] = (UInt8)(crc2 >> 8);

    NSData *testDataAssembledPacketObject = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:testDataAssembledPacket length:sizeof(testDataAssembledPacket)];

    [_myParentWindow printMessage: [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Sending buffer: %@",     testDataAssembledPacketObject]];

[self.activePeripheral writeValue:testDataAssembledPacketObject forCharacteristic:_serial_pass_characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

}

The device, if of use, is the Bean from Lightblue.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share some code?  I have only used the Bean library from Punchthrough but never had an issue.

Comment: Hi Paul, posted my code above. I don't want to use the library as want a lean app and only need to implement a simple LED light and button press function. The code above works, but only the first time you call it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that your write was failing the second time, its that your data isn't formatted correctly.  The [Bean protocol documentation](https://github.com/PunchThrough/bean-documentation/blob/master/serial_message_protocol.md) isn't the clearest (which is why it is much easier to use the SDK), but if you look closely at the format of the GT Header you will see that the two bit message count field needs to increment for each message.  As you have a fixed value the second and subsequent writes are being ignored by the Bean as duplicate messages.

I made the following changes to your code and I can toggle the LED -

```
@property char msgCount;

- (void) setLEDState {
    char testDataPacketStart[] = {0x80};
    testDataPacketStart[0]=testDataPacketStart[0] | (self.msgCount<<5);
    self.msgCount=++self.msgCount % 4;

    ...  The rest of your method unchanged
```

Comment: Jeez yes you're right. Thanks so much. The Bean is a great little device, but the documentation really sucks. Thanks for your help.